# Validations in Vue using Vuelidate are not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

**Hey guys**

I wonder if I miss something here, iv'e trying to figure it out for a few hours and didn't came up with a solution.

I'm trying to use form validations using Vuelidate in vue, everything seems in place but after the custom alert I created, the form is still proceeding to the next stage.

**I declared Vuelidate like this:**

```
import useVuelidate from '@vuelidate/core'
import { required } from '@vuelidate/validators'
```

**Inside Data() I did as follows:**

```
data: () => ({
    v$: useVuelidate(),
    currentStage: 1,
    traffic: {
      unique: '',
      unique1: '',
      unique2: '',
      unique3: '',
      unique4: ''
    },
  }),
```

**Declared validations outside of data(), like this:**

```
validations() {
    return {
      traffic: {
        unique1: { required },
        unique2: { required },
        unique3: { required },
        unique4: { required },
        unique5: { required }
      },
    }
  },
```

**Last thing is the computed, which I have function that is creating the input fields in stage 3 of the form:**

```
  computed: {

        appendFields() {
          this.v$.$validate()
          if(!this.v$.$error){
            if(this.jsonStatham.hasOwnProperty(this.traffic.unique1)){
              this.integrationParams.push(...Object.keys(this.jsonStatham[this.traffic.unique1]))
            }
          } else {
            alert("Error, Not all fields are filled in.")
          }
        }
      },
```

So here is the problem, when appendFields() called, I do get this alert: alert("Error, Not all fields are filled in.")
But After I press "ok" in the alert, the form is still proceeding to the next stage.
What am I missing?

**Edit:
This is the button who execute the "appendFields" method:**

```
<button @click="buttonClicked(0); appendFields;">Next Stage</button>
```

And this is buttonClicked function:

```
 buttonClicked(value) {
      if(value === 0){
        this.currentStage++;
        return this.currentStage;
      }
      if(value === 1){
        this.currentStage--;
        return this.currentStage;
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click`-handler updates `currentStage` without first validating the form. However, the validation occurs in `appendFields`, which is computed *after* `buttonClicked()`. The validation should be the first step, which can block the proceeding steps.

I would refactor it like this:

1. Make `appendFields` a component `method`, since it's not really a computed property (especially because it returns nothing).
2. Move the `currentStage` update into its own function for clarity.
3. Move the form validation from `appendFields()` to the button's `click`-handler.
4. In the `click`-handler, call the functions created in step 1 and 2 if the form is valid.

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    // 1️⃣
    appendFields() {
      if (this.jsonStatham.hasOwnProperty(this.traffic.unique1)) { 
this.integrationParams.push(...Object.keys(this.jsonStatham[this.traffic.unique1]))
      }
    },
    // 2️⃣
    updateStage(value) {
      if (value === 0) {
        this.currentStage++
      } else if (value === 1) {
        this.currentStage--
      }
    },
    buttonClicked(value) {
      // 3️⃣
      this.v$.$validate()

      if (!this.v$.$error) {
        // 4️⃣
        this.appendFields()
        this.updateStage(value)

      } else {
        alert("Error, Not all fields are filled in.")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also be aware that [`useValidate()` is intended for the Composition API](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/#getting-started-2), so it should be called inside `setup()`:

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      v$: useValidate()
    }
  }
}
```